# How to pad a 3rd dimention in an array of NP arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

I want to pad a 3rd dimension of an array with zeros, here is what I try:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]), np.array([[1,2],[2,3,4, 5]])]
lar =  []
for r in arr: 
    for e in r:
        lar.append(len(e))
        
i = max(lar)
for (ii, r) in enumerate(arr): 
    for (i, e) in enumerate(r):
       print(i)
       print(e)
       arr[ii][i]= np.pad(e, (0,i), 'constant' ) 
print(i)
print(lar)
print(arr)
```

Yet it fails as soon as it has to resise the first subarray, desired result:

```
[[[1,2,3,0]
[1,2,3,0]],
[[1,2,0,0],
[2,3,4,5]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a remark that *Numpy* does **not** support jagged arrays (with different
lengths in any dimension).

Another detail to mention is that your source "array" (*arr*) is actually not any array,
but a **list** of *Numpy* arrays.

Each element of this list is:

- either a "regular" 2-D *Numpy* array (if all sizes are the same in
  each dimension),
- or a 1-D array, containing lists (of different size) and the whole
  element is an array of *object* type.

So the proper way to approach the problem is to perform padding 2 diferent ways,
according to the type of each row.

Write the following function:

```
def myPad(arr):
    lar =  []
    for r in arr: 
        for e in r:
            lar.append(len(e))
    n = max(lar)
    rv = []
    for row in arr:
        if row.ndim == 1:  # A jagged array (1-D array of lists (of different lengths))
            rv.append(np.array([ col + [0] * (n - len(col)) for col in row ]))
        else:              # 2-D array (all rows of same length)
            rv.append(np.pad(row, ((0, 0), (0, n - row.shape[1]))))
    return np.array(rv)
```

It starts from your code to determine the target size (*n*).

Then there is a loop, processing each row, with a "fork" (*if*) according to
the number of dimensions of the current row;

- *if* path processes the case of a "jagged" array,
- *else* path processes the case of a "regular" array.

When you call:

```
result = myPad(arr)
```

The result, for your source data, is:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 0]],
       [[1, 2, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 4, 5]]])
```

and its shape (*result.shape*) is:

```
(2, 2, 4)
```